# Question about levelling skills as a software developer

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to ask a question about the resources available for a self-taught developer to level skills and conceptual understanding with a professional CS undergraduate curriculum.

Is this a suitable question for this site?

Comment: For any visiting this later to see whats become of this - the chat bookmark [On CS books and topics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/conversation/on-cs-books-and-topics) starting with [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=14980393#14980393).

Answer (score 3):

This is a suitable question for our chatroom, [the Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). It is most active during weekdays but someone is usually around every few hours on any given day. It's too personal and open ended for the main site.